# React different value of props in render and componentDidUpdate?

Tags: reactjs

I faced a weird situation with React 15.1.0 wherein the lifecycle hook `componentDidUpdate` shows different value of props than `render` method. The value of props in render method is the correct and latest. As per docs:

> componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs.

I am confused if this is the correct behaviour? I have to get the latest value of props to set the focus appropriately? Should I get props from any other lifecycle hook?

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props.nameEntered); // shows correct values
    return (
       ...
    );
}

componentDidUpdate() {
   console.log(this.props.nameEntered); // shows incorrect/outdated values
}
```

Comment: try to call it like: componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState); what does prevProps show in console?

Comment: prevProps.nameEntered gives me undefined, this.props.nameEntered gives me false but in render this.props.nameEntered gives me true.

Comment: Could you reproduce this thing on codesandbox/codepen? The above code is not helpful to find the mistake.